# Confused with calculating convolutional arrays on Rust and Python

Tags: python, rust, convolution

So, I am currently translating an equation on rust, which functions will be used in Python. For your reference, here's the equation:
[(Equation Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBfS6.png)

I have two questions regarding the convolution process that I am currently working on:

1. How to determine the shape required for convolutional arrays? For example, in the code, I stated that `convolve[[m,j]]` is the shape of (number of time x number of available producer wells), but I have my doubt.
2. Why does these calculations results in **very large values**? Is it related to `Question 1`, which causes the calculation to be wrong? For your reference, I have also attached the snippet of the results. These values will be used for optimization (through `scipy.minimize`), with these results being inputted into the loss function required for optimization. When calculating the `mean squared error`, using `np.mean()`, the large values of the results is calculated as `NaN`, which causes the optimization to fail.

```
# Results snippet
[[5.68561108e+001 5.61980823e+001 5.61675861e+001 5.61661613e+001]
 [2.35307528e+002 2.34679642e+002 2.34608585e+002 2.34637574e+002]
 [7.18489028e+003 7.18386393e+003 7.18388719e+003 7.18351637e+003]
 [1.90516275e+005 1.90523205e+005 1.90512232e+005 1.90519840e+005]
 [3.74431205e+006 3.74488940e+006 3.74428963e+006 3.74486795e+006]
 [8.66579029e+007 8.66498208e+007 8.66607474e+007 8.66526724e+007]
 [2.07434218e+009 2.07448157e+009 2.07428866e+009 2.07442773e+009]
 [4.66149113e+010 4.66176532e+010 4.66161252e+010 4.66188671e+010]
 [7.41128735e+011 7.41177498e+011 7.41146858e+011 7.41195646e+011]
 [1.25832053e+013 1.25839703e+013 1.25759536e+013 1.25767179e+013]
 [3.13527991e+014 3.13539602e+014 3.13626007e+014 3.13637621e+014]
 ...
 [6.05974959e+285 6.06077063e+285 6.05912366e+285 6.06014464e+285]
 [1.19827323e+287 1.19782672e+287 1.19831491e+287 1.19786874e+287]
 [2.86110632e+288 2.86121783e+288 2.86107733e+288 2.86118882e+288]
 [5.59234029e+289 5.59217971e+289 5.59188827e+289 5.59172842e+289]
 [1.19840987e+291 1.19841850e+291 1.19834897e+291 1.19835744e+291]
 [2.51358782e+292 2.51380008e+292 2.51383269e+292 2.51404447e+292]
 [4.99748565e+293 4.99665753e+293 4.99716953e+293 4.99634444e+293]]
```

The codes on rust is as follows:

```
fn proxy_crm(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    fn q_prim(prod: ArrayView2<'_, f64>, time: ArrayView1<'_, f64>, lambda_prod: ArrayView1<'_, f64>, tau_prim: ArrayView1<'_, f64>) -> Array1<f64> {
        let n_prod: usize = prod.raw_dim()[1];
        let mut result: Array1<f64> = Array1::zeros([n_prod]);

        for j in 0..n_prod {
            let time_decay = (-&time / tau_prim[j]).mapv(f64::exp);
            result[j] = time_decay[j] * prod[[0,j]] * lambda_prod[j]
        }
        result
    }

    fn q_crm(inj: ArrayView2<'_, f64>, time: ArrayView1<'_, f64>, lambda_ip: ArrayView2<'_, f64>, tau: ArrayView1<'_, f64>, mask: ArrayView2<'_, f64> ) -> Array2<f64> {
        let n_t: usize = time.raw_dim()[0];
        let n_inj: usize = lambda_ip.raw_dim()[1];
        let n_prod: usize = mask.raw_dim()[1];
        let mut convolve: Array2<f64> = Array2::zeros([n_t, n_prod]);
        
        let lambda_ip_mod = calc_sh_mask(lambda_ip, mask);

        for i in 0..n_inj {
            for j in 0..n_prod {
                convolve[[0,j]] = (1.0 - ((time[0] - time[1]) / tau[j]).exp()) * lambda_ip_mod[[0,j,i]] * inj[[0,i]];
                for m in 1..n_t {
                    for n in 1..m+1 {
                        let time_decay = (1.0 - ((time[m-1] - time[m]) / tau[j]).exp()) * ((time[n] - time[m]) / tau[j]).exp();

                        convolve[[m,j]] += time_decay * lambda_ip_mod[[m,j,i]] * inj[[m,i]];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        convolve
    }

    fn q_bhp(time: ArrayView1<'_, f64>, tau: ArrayView1<'_, f64>, press: ArrayView2<'_, f64>, prod_index: ArrayView1<'_, f64>) -> Array2<f64> {
        let n_t = time.raw_dim()[0];
        let n_prod = press.raw_dim()[1];
        let mut convolve: Array2<f64> = Array2::zeros([n_t,n_prod]);
        
        for j in 0..n_prod {
            convolve[[0,j]] = (1.0 - ((time[0] - time[1]) / tau[j]).exp()) * prod_index[0] * tau[j] * (press[[1,0]]-press[[0,0]]) / (time[1]-time[0]);
            for m in 1..n_t {
                for n in 1..m+1 {
                    let time_decay = (1.0 - ((time[m-1] - time[m]) / tau[j]).exp()) * ((time[n] - time[m]) / tau[j]).exp();
                    let delta_bhp = press[[m-1,j]] - press[[m,j]];

                    convolve[[m,j]] += time_decay * prod_index[j] * tau[j] * (delta_bhp / (time[m-1]-time[m]));
                }
            }
        }
        convolve
    }

    fn sh_mask(prod: ArrayView2<'_, f64>) -> Array2<f64> {
        let n_prod: usize = prod.raw_dim()[1];
        let n_t: usize = prod.raw_dim()[0];
        let mut mask = Array2::zeros([n_t, n_prod]);

        for t in 0..n_t {
            for j in 0..n_prod {
                if prod[[t,j]] == 0.0 {
                    mask[[t,j]] = 1.0;
                }
            }
        }
        mask
    }

    fn calc_sh_mask(lambda_ip:ArrayView2<'_, f64>, mask: ArrayView2<'_, f64>) -> Array3<f64> {
        let n_prod: usize = mask.raw_dim()[1];
        let n_inj: usize = lambda_ip.raw_dim()[1];
        let n_t: usize = mask.raw_dim()[0];
        
        let tensor: Array3<f64> = Array3::ones([n_t,n_prod,n_inj]);
        let mut lambda_ip_result: Array3<f64> = Array3::zeros([n_t,n_prod,n_inj]);

        for t in 0..n_t {
            let mut sum_lambda_sh: Array1<f64> = Array1::zeros([n_inj]);
            for j in 0..n_prod {
                for i in 0..n_inj {
                    lambda_ip_result[[t,j,i]] = f64::abs(f64::abs((mask[[t,j]]-1.0) * lambda_ip[[j,i]]) * (tensor[[t,j,i]] + tensor[[t,j,i]] * mask[[t,j]]));
                    if mask[[t,j]] == 1.0 {
                        sum_lambda_sh[i] += lambda_ip[[j,i]];
                        for k in 0..n_prod {
                            if k!=j {
                                lambda_ip_result[[t, k, i]] += f64::abs(f64::abs(lambda_ip[[k,i]]) * (tensor[[t,j,i]] + sum_lambda_sh[i] * tensor[[t,j,i]] * mask[[t,j]]));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        lambda_ip_result
    }
```

I adapted those codes with the reference of a repository on GitHub, and will link it here if it helps.

Comment: It seems to me you don't have a programming problem but rather a [maths problem](https://math.stackexchange.com)⁉

Comment: I think it's more like a 'translating' problem, so I thought that I have more of a coding problem rather than maths problem. I'm new to the forum and I'm sorry that I have misunderstood it. Should I go to math stackexchange instead in this case?